# Recovering partitions from a Windows 7 NTFS drive HDD drive that was inserted into a NAS and set with new, Linux partitions

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, nas

I had a netbook with NTFS formatted SATA HDD. There was Windows 7 installed inside.

I ejected HDD from netbook and inserted to [QNAP TS-212P](http://www.qnap.com/i/en/product/model.php?II=117) NAS enclosure to copy all contents of netbook’s HDD directly into NAS HDD. NAS recognized HDD as a drive but showed partitions as unmounted.

I didn’t try to mount using SSH instead I just ejected netbook’s HDD and inserted to another PC with Windows 7 installed. Windows stuck while recognizing partitions.

Tried several partition table tools like Easus Partition Wizard, NTFS Get Data Back etc. and recovered files. About 60-70% of files recovered. but 30-40% damaged. What this software does is always lossy. It looks to HDD as damaged HDD and finds files by physical sectors. This method is always lossy.

I think my partitions with data are not damaged. But NAS did something to netbook’s HDD’s partition table. Because when I try to recover partitions on PC I saw some Linux partitions (ext3) inside HDD. (this HDD never used with Linux distro). I think the NAS created this partitions.

What can I do, in this situtation to fully copy all contents of partitions without any damage?
Is there any way to fully rebuild partition table and get files?

Comment: Once you've blown the partition tables, & hence any other file records, the only thing you can do is trawl the drive for recognisable bits of file & hope they were written contiguously. [Recuver](https://www.piriform.com/recuva) etc would be as good as anything for that. A good backup strategy would be better.

Comment: The MFT (Master File Table) is probably still there, [try using testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover it, or save yourself time and pay someone to recover the data if it is important enough.